# Efficient joins in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql, distributed-computing

I am trying to join a DataFrame (dfA) sequentially on the same DataFrame.
Let's say dfA has columns `id_x` and `id_y` and dfB has the column `id` and some other columns.

I want to do perform the following:

```
dfA.join(dfB, dfA("id_x") === dfB("id")).join(dfB, dfA("id_y") === dfB("id"))
```

Is there any sort of repartitioning or preprocessing that I can do to speed this up?

Answer (score 1):

What version of spark you are using?
Tuning Spark is art and is a vast topic by itself. Just blindly increasing the number of partitions does not always help. I would suggest to look at the following places for clue:

1. Have a close look at the Spark UI and analyse your DAG. Where is the bottleneck? Is it waiting for CPU, Memory, Disk IO? Too much shuffle?
2. Is your data skewed? Few tasks are long running while most of them finishing quickly?
3. What sort of transform you used? Please paste your code excerpt if possible.
4. Bucketing is something new in Spark which is broadly expected to help with joins. But investigating your DAG is always the best source for clue.
5. Also based on your code, on which occasion you want to  use dfA("id_x") and dfA("id_y") to join with dfB("id")? You can probably try something below rather than OR in the join condition

   val joinCondition = when($"dfA.id_y".isNull, $"dfA.id_y"===$"dfB.id")
   .otherwise($"dfA.id_x"===$"dfB.id")

   val dfJoined = dfA.join(dfB, joinCondition)

Please let me know your findings.

Answer (score 0):

you could do that in 1 join:

```
dfA.join(dfB, dfA("id_x") === dfB("id") or dfA("id_y") === dfB("id"))
```

you could also play with `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` or try to broadcast one dataframe. A repartitioning prior to the join will not help, but using bucketed tables could help because this could avoid doing a reparitioning during the join, see e.g. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12394

Comment: Please elaborate for the benefit of others on  "A repartitioning prior to the join will not help." @Raphael Roth

Comment: @thebluephantom I'm not sure what you mean. AFAIK the only thing that could improve performance would be using hives bucketing feature since spark 2.0 (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12394)

Comment: You make a very definite statement otherwise. Daniel problem would want to know why you stated that.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Thanks! I have played with spark.sql.shuffle.partitions but I am already at a very high number (4000-8000) and both dataframes are ~300m records so broadcasting is not really feasibly. I will look into hive bucketing.